# Ansible win_shell with JSON to powershell, works fine other way

Tags: json, powershell, variables, ansible

I can not get how to get win_shell to send JSON to a powershell script on a windows server. If I run this:

```
vm:
  annotation: This is a VM
  cdrom:
    type: client
    iso_path: ''
    controller_type: ''
    state: ''
  cluster: ''
- name: "Run script '.ps1'"
    win_shell: D:\scripts\outputValues.ps1 -vm "{{vm}}"
    register: result
  - name: Process win_shell output
    set_fact:
      fullResult: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"
```

I get this string into powershell that I can not even convert TO JSON:

```
{u'cdrom': {u'controller_type': u'', u'state': u'', u'type': u'client', u'iso_path': u''}, u'cluster': u'', u'annotation': u'This is a VM'}
```

If I run the script with this:

```
win_shell: D:\scripts\outputValues.ps1 -vm "{{vm | to_json}}"
```

All I get is an open curly bracket '{' into powershell.

It does work the other way. As a test, if I call that same powershell script from win_shell and ignore the input in powershell and simply create an object like this and send it back to ansible, it works fine. Why can I send JSON one way and not the other? I have tried vm|to_json etc.

```
#Powershell
$vmAttribs = @{"type" = "client"; "iso_path" = ""; "controller_type" =""; "state" =""}
$vmObject = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    annotation = 'This is a VM'
    cdrom = $vmAttribs
    cluster = ""
}
$result = $vmObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 8
Write-Output $result
```

ansible gets:

```
{
    "msg": {
        "cdrom": {
            "controller_type": "",
            "state": "",
            "type": "client",
            "iso_path": ""
        },
        "cluster": "",
        "annotation": "This is a VM"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a Python structure signifying JSON notation with Unicode strings (e.g. `u'my string value'`). Obviously, that's not exactly portable to *other* runtimes like Powershell, and results in an invalid string.

Reading up on [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html), you will want to use `{{ vm | to_json }}` to ensure that the data structure is stringified to JSON correctly.

## Workaround

> I want to stress that this is not the ideal way of getting a JSON object out of Ansible, and a proper solution that doesn't involve hacking out the Unicode identifier from the JSON string is desirable to this.

I don't know enough about Ansible to know why the string becomes `{` when piping `vm` to `to_json`, but here's a workaround that might get you going until someone else can chime in with what is going on with Ansible's filtering here.

In your `.ps1` script, you can use the following `-replace` to remove those `u` characters before the strings:

```
$vm = $vm -replace "u(?=([`"']).*\1)"
```

You can test this by running the following in an interactive terminal:

```
"{u'cdrom': {u'controller_type': u'', u'state': u'', u'type': u'client', u'iso_path': u''}, u'cluster': u'', u'annotation': u'This is a VM'}" -replace "u(?=([`"']).*\1)"
```

The pattern matches on the `u` character that comes immediately before a single-quote or double-quote followed by any number of characters (including none) followed by another single-quote or double quote, whichever was matched the first time. `-replace` does not require a second argument if you are replacing the pattern with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you. My original post had an error, I fixed it. I have tried win_shell: D:\scripts\outputValues.ps1 -vm "{{vm | to_json}}"
All I get is an open curly bracket '{' into powershell.

Comment: I added a workaround that might work in your case. Unfortunately, I'm not sure why `to_json` isn't working in your case :(

Comment: I am thinking that the reason I get just the { into powershell is that there is newline after that and powershell interprets that as the end of the input string. Also the -replace you suggested does work, but since it is still a sting, it is going to be hard to parse that back into JSON.

Comment: Nevermind, I can convert it using convertfrom-json in powershell. Good workaround at least, thanks.

Comment: JSON is a string. I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Ahh you meant turn it back into an object. Yeah you can `ConvertFrom-Json` in Powershell, and actually you'd have to do that anyways, even if you were passing in a valid JSON string from the start.